# How to share one ELB for multiple servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Can we create an AWS ELB in the following way. My objective is to share one ELB for multiple servers/applications

- https://www.example.com/123 --> goes into EC2 instances-1
- https://www.example.com/456 --> goes into EC2 instances-2

Answer (score 3):

For this Scenario you use [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) and use [Path Based Routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html).

You can read more about Listeners for Application Load Balancing from [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html).

Hope It Helps!